# Image as Proptype or pass from parent to child as a string?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

So I have been wondering where best to load an image.

I have a parent component like so:

```
import img from "../img.png"

class Parent extends Component {
    render(){
        <Child img={img}/>
}
```

The downside of this approach is that I can not really specify a proptype for the image (is there a type image?). I i've read somewhere that I should pass the image as a string and import it in the child. But I don't really know what that would look like **since I obviously don't want to import a specific image to the child and sacrifice reusability.**

Thanks

Comment: `img` is already a string in the code you posted.

Comment: If you're considering reusability of the component. Passing the path and not the base64 data for the image may be better approach. I'd move the images to the assets folder and pass relative source paths as prop where I need it.